# How to load php file on localhost in phonegap

Tags: php, html, cordova, android-emulator, phonegap-plugins

Hello i am new in phonegap. i am create a one html file with login validation. my validation code in php file. and i am run on android emulator. that time this php file is not working on emulator so what can i do?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>
        </title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
        <style>
            /* App custom styles */
        </style>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"> </script>
        <script src="my.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="page1">
            <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <div id="message" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="textinput1">
                            Email:
                        </label>
                        <input name="" id="textinput1" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnValidate').click(function() {

        $('#message').hide(500);

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url : 'http://localhost/JQuery/php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data: {
                email : $('#textinput1').val()
            },
            success : function(data){
                $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                    .text(data.msg).show(500);
            },
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>

<a data-role="button" data-inline="true"  id="btnValidate" data-transition="fade" href="#page1">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            //App custom javascript
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my html code. where i was incorrect so please tall me.

Comment: Is the php code supposed to run on the phone or on a server?

Answer (score 2):

When you run an a PhoneGap application in the Android emulator, localhost and 127.0.0.1 refer to [the Android emulator loopback interface](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses). You can access the development machine using the IP address 10.0.2.2

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'http://10.0.2.2/JQuery/php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {
        email : $('#textinput1').val()
    }...
```

Comment: when i was run html that time call the error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                    .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            } On MY HTML file

Comment: Do you have a firewall running blocking port 80 on  your machine? If that's the case, you must open that port in your firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to access your php file by using IP address of your system (something like 192.168.1.2)  or setup a virtualhost. Android emulator is loaded as a separate virtual machine so you cannot access localhost for your php files.

Comment: how to set android emulator ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Assing IP to your system and use That IP addrerss http:// 183.82.166.97:9696/index.php

I configured like this in httpd.conf

Listen 9696

    DocumentRoot "D:/PHPworkspace/HWsite"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    
    
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All